# Why does java not have the Try monad?

Tags: java, try-catch, monads

In my opinion, Java 8 and later versions (actually 9 and 10) lack of a piece to efficiently use `Stream` and other monads. Java does not have any kind of `Try` monad to handle errors during monad composition.

Why? Initially, I thought that was a lack of only the version 8, but I do not find any [JEP](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/0) to introduce it in the JDK.

Something like the following could be a starting point.

```
public class Try<T> {
    private T value;
    private Exception exception;

    private Try(Supplier<T> supplier) {
        try {
            this.value = supplier.get();
        } catch (Exception ) {
            this.exception = ex;
        }
    }

    Optional<T> toOptional() {
        return Optional.ofNullable(value);
    }

    public static <T> Try<T> of(Supplier<T> supplier) {
        return new Try<>(supplier);
    }
    // Some other interesting methods...
}
```

Maybe not anyone uses reactive streams, but during a stream transformation, you need some smart way to collect exceptions, without breaking the whole stream execution.

```
stream
   .map(info -> {
        // Code that can rise an exception
        // Without the Try monad is tedious to handle exceptions!
   })
   .filter(/* something */)
   .to(/* somewhere */)
```

Can anyone explain me why? Is it related to some other specification lack?

Thanks to all.

Comment: Why is the Java language like it is? Why isn't it like some other language?

Comment: Out of the interest, how would something like this look like in Java syntax?

Comment: Wait, here we are talking about a feature related to functional programming. Without the `Try` monad you cannot handle exception effectively during monad composition.

Comment: @lexicore, the same as the `Optional` monad, `Try.of(() -> {...})`

Comment: @riccardo.cardin Could you write a more complete example please? Like some real-world use case. Quite interesting.

Comment: It is considered functional approach have no side effect functions i.e. exception can not be thrown.

Comment: Although interesting, it is still off-topic.

Comment: @VictorGubin, no exception cannot escape from inner contexts.

Comment: @lexicore, I edit my question with some code snippets

Comment: Look also here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27787772/try-monad-in-java-8

Comment: @riccardo.cardin Thanks, but still missing the real-world use case.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose I don’t ask if there is any library implementing it, but why it is not part of language specification.

Comment: Well ... And this is opinionated.

Comment: Why? I am not asking about opinions, but something that refers to specification lacks

Comment: How shall we know, why something is or is not the way it is? Maybe you should ask the designers of Java. SO is the wrong place.

Comment: In SO, there also the Java architects and designers

Comment: One important thing to remember is that Java is actually not a functional programming language. It's an OO language. Therefore asking why it's missing some particular aspect of functional programming is pretty useless.

Comment: @Kayaman, however java has Optional and Streams. Why not Try?

Comment: Why should there be Try? Why would the existence of Optional and Streams in anyway dictate that there should be Try? Why do you compare Java to other languages and are surprised that they're different? Just because there's Optional and Streams, Java is still not a functional language. If you can't get your head around that, there's not much to we can do. I recommend you compare things to Clojure, as that **is** a functional language.